# How to install sstp vpn client on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, vpn

Please tell me how to install the client sstp on the centos. Preferably with the use of UI. Google search did not return any result I use centos 8 with a gnome.

```
Operating System: CentOS Stream 8
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-315.el8.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
Gnome Version 3.32.2
```

Comment: CentOS 8 is made from Fedora 28 : `# dnf install ./sstp-client-1.0.11-10.fc28.x86_64.rpm` I.e. you can try with a downloaded package from Fedora 28 https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/s/

Comment: its work! Thanks!